# Problemas com Cookies de login

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, cookies

Na pagina de login ao usuario enviar o formulario com seus dados de login, registra os dados em cookies e redireciona para outra pagina. Mas estou sofrendo problema se o usuario fazer logout, eu queria excluir os cookies, na pagina de login tenho uma verificacao se o cookies existem ele redericiona automaticamente para uma pagina onde faz verificação dos dados(mesma pagina onde registro os cookies). Porem para isso funcionar teria que excluir esse cookie para que se nao existisse ele teria que escrever os dados novamente no formulario. Segue Código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php

#PAGINA DO FORMULARIO DE LOGIN


    include "seguranca/banco/ff_conexao_banco.php";
    include "componentes/php/ff_operacaobd_php.php"; #inclui a pagina operation nas paginas administrativas!
    include "componentes/php/ff_expressoes_php.php"; #inclui a pagina das validações de expressao nas paginas do front-end!
    include "componentes/php/ff_mensagens_php.php"; #inclui a pagina safedelete nas paginas administrativas!
  #verifica os dados!
    if(isset($_COOKIE['lembrarUsuario'])){
        $usuarioCookie = base64_encode($_COOKIE['lembrarUsuario']);

    }else{
        $usuarioCookie==NULL;
    }

    if(isset($_COOKIE['lembrarSenha'])){
        $senhaCookie = base64_encode($_COOKIE['lembrarSenha']);
    }else{
        $senhaCookie==NULL;
    }
  # se os dados existem ele manda pra pagina de verificação
    if($usuarioCookie AND $senhaCookie){
        header("location: seguranca/autenticacao/ff_login_autenticacao.php?usuarioCookie=$usuarioCookie&senhaCookie=$senhaCookie");




?>


    <?php
    }else{
    ?>
    <html lang="pt-br">
        <head>
            <title>Floricultura Filippi - Pedidos</title>
            <meta name="author" content="Gabriel Filippi, Rhuan Carvalho, Bruna Campioli, Melissa Possamai" />
            <meta name="description" content="Gerenciamento de Pedidos da Floricultura Filippi" />
            <meta name="keywords" content="Pedidos, entrega, floricultura filippi" />
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
            <link rel="icon" href="layout/imagens/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

            <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
            <link href="componentes/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

            <!-- CSS PADRÃO DO TEMPLATE -->
            <link href="layout/css/template_default.css" rel="stylesheet">

            <!-- Custom Fonts -->
            <link href="componentes/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

            <!--  CSS Gabriel, Rhuan, Bruna, Melissa-->
            <link href="layout/css/ff_style_frontend.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

            <!-- jQuery -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="componentes/plugins/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>


            <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
            <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->
        </head>
        <body>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text " style="text-align: center;">
                <img src="layout/imagens/logo.png" class="logo">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading painel_login">
                      <h2>Login!</h2>
                      <h5>Entre com seu nome de Usuário ou E-mail e Senha:</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body painel_login">
                    <form name="frmlogin" method="POST" action="index.php?folder=seguranca/autenticacao/&file=ff_login_autenticacao&ext=php">
                      <fieldset class="fieldset_login">

                          <?php

                            if(isset($_GET['folder'])&&isset($_GET['file'])&&isset($_GET['ext'])){
                              if(!include $_GET['folder'].$_GET['file'].".".$_GET['ext']){
                                echo "<h1>Página não encontrada</h1>";
                              }else{
                              ?>
                                <script>
                                    $(document).ready(function() {
                                        $('.footerfront').css('bottom',"-95px");
                                    });
                                </script>
                              <?php
                              }
                            }
                          ?>
                        <div class="form-group">

                          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtusuario" maxlength="70" placeholder="E-mail ou Usuario"  autofocus>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input class="form-control" type="password" name="pwdsenha" maxlength="32" placeholder="●●●●●●●●●●●●"  >
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                          <label>
                              <input type="checkbox" name="chkusuario" value="lembreme">Lembre-me
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" name="button">Login!</button>
                      </fieldset>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <footer style="background-color: #e4e1e1 !important;" class="footerfront">
            <?php
              $datacopy = date('Y');
            ?>
            <div class="row" style="margin-right: 0px;   margin-left: 0px;">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <p class="direitos_autorais">© Copyright <?php echo $datacopy; ?> - <a href="http://www.floriculturafilippi.com.br/" target="_blank" >Floricultura Filippi</a>. Todos os direitos reservados. - <a href="_licencas/loader.php">Licenciamento</a></p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3">
                <span class="fa fa-whatsapp"></span>
                <b style="text-align: right;"> (47) 99218-3829</b>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3">
                <span class="fa fa-phone"></span>
                <b> (47) 3439-1090</b>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
          </footer>
      </body>
    </html>
    <?php       
    }
    ?>



+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
PAGINA ONDE VERIFICA OS DADOS E TBM REGISTRA OS COOKIES
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

<?php
# se dados da cookie existir armazena na variavel
if(isset($_GET["usuarioCookie"])){
    include "../banco/ff_conexao_banco.php";
    $p_usuario = base64_decode($_COOKIE['lembrarUsuario']);
    $p_senha = base64_decode($_COOKIE['lembrarSenha']);
    $hash_senha = MD5($salt.$p_senha); // criptografar a senha
}else{
  # se nao armazena na variavel os dados do formulario
    $p_usuario = $_POST['txtusuario']; 
    $p_senha = $_POST['pwdsenha'];
    $hash_senha = MD5($salt.$p_senha); 
}
$aviso = "Erro ao se autenticar"; /* TITULO do painel */
$cor = "panel-red"; /* cor do painel */

if($p_usuario==""){
    $msg = buildMessage('senha', 'Usuário');
}else if($p_senha==""){
    $msg = buildMessage('senha', 'Senha');
    }else{
        $sql_sel_usuario = "SELECT usuarios.id, usuarios.usuario, usuarios.senha, administradores.email, administradores.status, administradores_terceirizados.status, entregadores.status, funcionarios.status, administradores_terceirizados.email, entregadores.email, funcionarios.email, usuarios.permissao FROM usuarios LEFT JOIN administradores ON usuarios.id = administradores.usuarios_id LEFT JOIN funcionarios ON usuarios.id = funcionarios.usuarios_id LEFT JOIN entregadores ON usuarios.id = entregadores.usuarios_id LEFT JOIN administradores_terceirizados ON usuarios.id = administradores_terceirizados.usuarios_id WHERE (administradores.status=0 OR funcionarios.status=0 OR entregadores.status=0 OR administradores_terceirizados.status=0) AND (BINARY usuarios.usuario='".$p_usuario."' OR BINARY administradores.email='".$p_usuario."' OR BINARY administradores_terceirizados.email='".$p_usuario."' OR BINARY funcionarios.email='".$p_usuario."' OR BINARY entregadores.email='".$p_usuario."') AND BINARY usuarios.senha='".$hash_senha."'";
        $sql_sel_usuario_preparado = $conexaobd->prepare($sql_sel_usuario);
        $sql_sel_usuario_preparado->execute();
        $sql_sel_usuario_dados = $sql_sel_usuario_preparado->fetch();
        if($sql_sel_usuario_preparado->rowCount()>0){
            if(isset($_POST["chkusuario"])){
                $p_senha = $_POST['pwdsenha'];
                setcookie("lembrarUsuario",  base64_encode($p_usuario), (time() + (3 * 24 * 3600))); /* duração de 3 dias*/
                setcookie("lembrarSenha",  base64_encode($p_senha), (time() + (3 * 24 * 3600))); /* duração de 3 dias*/
            }
            //guardando as informações dentro de array
            //iniciando sessão
            session_start();
            //armazenamento do id do usuario para sabermos quem está autenticando
            $_SESSION['idUsuario'] = $sql_sel_usuario_dados['id'];
            //armazenamento do usuario para mostrarmos nas telas do back-end
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $sql_sel_usuario_dados['usuario'];
            //armazenamento da permissão para sabermos o que ele pode acessar
            $_SESSION['permissao'] = $sql_sel_usuario_dados['permissao'];
            //armazenamento do id da SESSÃO para futura implementação de segurança
            $_SESSION['idSessao'] = session_id();
            if(isset($_GET["usuarioCookie"])){
                if($sql_sel_usuario_dados['permissao']==0 AND $sql_sel_usuario_dados['status']==0){
                header('location: ../../sistema/admin/ff_admin.php');
                }else if($sql_sel_usuario_dados['permissao']==1 AND $sql_sel_usuario_dados['status']==0){
                  header('location: ../../sistema/funcionario/ff_funcionario.php');
                    }else if($sql_sel_usuario_dados['permissao']==2 AND $sql_sel_usuario_dados['status']==0){
                      header('location: ../../sistema/admin_terceirizada/ff_admin_terceirizada.php');
                        }else if($sql_sel_usuario_dados['permissao']==3 AND $sql_sel_usuario_dados['status']==0){
                          header('location: ../../sistema/entregador/ff_entregador.php');
                            }else{
                                $msg = buildMessage('usuario_permissao', 'Permissão');
                            }   
            }else{
                if($sql_sel_usuario_dados['permissao']==0 AND $sql_sel_usuario_dados['status']==0){
                header('location: sistema/admin/ff_admin.php');
                }else if($sql_sel_usuario_dados['permissao']==1 AND $sql_sel_usuario_dados['status']==0){
                  header('location: sistema/funcionario/ff_funcionario.php');
                    }else if($sql_sel_usuario_dados['permissao']==2 AND $sql_sel_usuario_dados['status']==0){
                      header('location: sistema/admin_terceirizada/ff_admin_terceirizada.php');
                        }else if($sql_sel_usuario_dados['permissao']==3 AND $sql_sel_usuario_dados['status']==0){
                          header('location: sistema/entregador/ff_entregador.php');
                            }else{
                                $msg = buildMessage('usuario_permissao', 'Permissão');
                            }   
            }

            }else{
                $msg = buildMessage('login', 'Usuário', 'Senha');
            }
    }
?>
<div class="mensagem col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel  <?php echo $cor ?>">
        <div class="panel-heading">
                <?php echo $aviso ?>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p><?php echo $msg;?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
PARA EXCLUIR OS COOKIES ESTOU USANDO O SEGUINTE CÓDIGO ABAIXO
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++



<?php
    session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    setcookie("lembrarUsuario",  base64_encode($_COOKIE['lembrarUsuario']), (time() - (3 * 24 * 3600)));
    setcookie("lembrarSenha",  base64_encode($_COOKIE['lembrarSenha']), (time() - (3 * 24 * 3600)));
    header ('location: ../../index.php?deslogado=true')
?>
```

Comment: Quando você "chamar" a página para um logout e excluir os cookies coloque um "?logout=1" p ex e põe um if antes do redirecionamento...

Comment: veja minha resposta editada

Comment: Seu código está cheio de erros, e muita coisa desnecessária, por mim recomeçava isso do `0`, e separava em partes menores, porque tentar corrigir isso chega a ser mais trabalhoso. A menos que você tenha formatado mal o código quando criaste a pergunta, está realmente caótico.

Comment: @Edilson só esta mal formatado aqui, no site esta separado em varias partes(paginas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que está ocasionando problemas é a função base64_encode retornar caracteres proibidos em nomes de cookies.

NA PAGINA ONDE VERIFICA OS DADOS E TBM REGISTRA OS COOKIES

faça assim:

```
$base64usuario= base64_encode($p_usuario);
$base64senha= base64_encode($p_senha);
$base64usuario = str_replace(array('=','+','/'),'',$base64usuario);
$base64senha = str_replace(array('=','+','/'),'',$base64senha);

setcookie("lembrarUsuario",  $base64usuario, (time() + (3 * 24 * 3600)), "/");
setcookie("lembrarSenha",  $base64senha, (time() + (3 * 24 * 3600)), "/");
```

> Os **nomes de cookies** devem consistir em caracteres ASCII.

Eles não podem conter

```
aspas duplas

espaço em branco

\ @ Ou # \?

Parênteses, colchetes ou chaves

Vírgulas, dois pontos ou ponto e vírgula

sinal de igual (=), sinais maior ou menor que (> <)

Barras ou barras invertidas
```

> Os **valores de cookie** devem consistir em caracteres ASCII.

Não podem conter:

```
Caracteres de controle

Caracteres de espaço em branco

Aspas duplas, exceto no início e no final se o valor inteiro for duplamente cotado

Vírgulas

Ponto-e-vírgula

Barras invertidas
```

Fontes

[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie)

[Cookies: HTTP State Management - by Jordan Johnson](https://docs.racket-lang.org/cookies/index.html)

Comment: Ja tenho essa pagina: <?php  session_start();  session_unset();  session_destroy();  setcookie("lembrarUsuario",  base64_encode($_COOKIE['lembrarUsuario']), (time() - (3 * 24 * 3600)));  setcookie("lembrarSenha",  base64_encode($_COOKIE['lembrarSenha']), (time() - (3 * 24 * 3600)));  header ('location: ../../index.php?deslogado=true') ?>

Comment: Então sua pergunta não está clara.

Comment: É que nao esta funcionando,  na pagina de login ele ja ta redirecionando automaticamente  como se ainda tivesse cookies salvo

Comment: ao criar os cookies você usou  $cookiePath = "/";

Comment: E  nao esta correto? Nao sei mt sobre cookies?

Comment: Desculpe a demora, resolveu meu problema muito obrigado